# Small doubt in Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

We know the following is true:
A space $X$ is contractible iff every map $f:X\to Y$, for arbitrary $Y$, is nullhomotopic.
(This is Ex9 in chapter $0$ of Hatcher's book)

The above basically implies that any two continuous maps with a contractible space as their domain will be homotopic.

***My question is the following***- Paths in a space $X$ are defined as continuous maps from $I$ to $X$, here $I$ denotes $[0,1]$. But $I$ is contractible (it's convex), this means any two paths are homotopic, which doesn't make sense.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to assume that $X$ is path-connected or two paths in different path components won't be homotopic even in this sense. But the usual definition of homotopy of paths is with fixed endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every loop $f:I\to X$ is null-homotopic, since $I$ is contractible. But it is not homotopic $\text{rel}\{0,1\}$ to the constant map at $f(0)$, that is homotopic with fixed end-points.

In general, the notion $f\simeq g \text{ rel }A$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $f,g$ are maps from $X$ to $Y$ means that there is a map $H:X\times I\to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x),\ H(x,1)=g(x)$ and $H(a,t)=f(a)=g(a)$ for all $x\in X,\ a\in A,\ t\in I$.

So to determine if two loops $f$ and $g$ in $X$ are in the same class in $\pi_1(X)$ we need to check if they are homotopic rel $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, stupid mistake. Thanks. In the above answer I believe you meant H(a,t)=f(a)=g(a) for all a in A and t in I.

Comment: Ah, of course I meant that :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have your definition backwards, if every map $f:X \to Y$ is homotopic for arbitrary $X$, then $Y$ is contractible. Even if $X$ is contractible  maps $g,f:X \to Y$ need not be homotopic, for example take $X$ to be a singleton set and $Y$ to have two elements.

Comment: "Every map is nullhomotopic" is not equivalent to "every pair of maps is homotopic."

Comment: Yes, you're right. Two maps can be homotopic to two different constant maps and hence need not be homotopic to each other.